# Is it possible to require modules from outside of your project directory without relative paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, require

I'm trying to build a local library of JS modules to use in Node projects.

If a new project lives in `/Users/me/projects/path/to/new/project/` and my library files are located in `/Users/me/projects/library/*.js` is there a way to access those files without using a relative path?

In `/Users/me/projects/path/to/new/project/app.js` you can require foo.js like so:

`var foo = require('../../../../../library/foo')` and that will work but that's clunky and if files move you'd have to update your relative paths.

I've tried [requireFrom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirefrom) and [app-module-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/app-module-path) with no luck as they are relative to a project root.

Any ideas for how to require files from outside of your project dir?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Is it possible to require modules from outside of your project directory without relative paths?" [yes](https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520).

Comment: Billy Moon's answer is correct. Try to add log statements inside requirelib function to see what path is being resolved.

Comment: app-module-path can take absolute paths. Did you try `require('app-module-path').addPath('/Users/me/projects/library')`

Answer (score 0):

```
var librarypath = '/Users/me/projects/library/';
// or if you prefer...
// var librarypath = '../../../../../library/';
var foo = require(librarypath + 'foo.js');
```

... or dressed up a bit more ...

```
function requirelib(lib){ return require('/Users/me/projects/library/'+lib+'.js'); }
var foo = requirelib('foo');
var bar = requirelib('bar');
```

Comment: thank you but this is returning an `Uncaught Error: Cannot find module` and the path is the correct one

Comment: Perhaps you need the `.js` extension in there too - I updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem many times. This can be solved by using the [`basetag`](https://github.com/janniks/basetag) npm package. It doesn't have to be required itself, only installed as it creates a symlink inside `node_modules` to your base path.

```
const localFile = require('$/local/file')
// instead of
const localFile = require('../../local/file')
```

Using the `$/...` prefix will always reference files relative to your apps root directory.

*[**Disclaimer**: I created `basetag` to solve this problem](https://link.medium.com/ezoQFJFDU5)*